# Objective C Segue identity

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have a pretty simple question. Say you have 2 view controllers A and B. A is a UITableView with STATIC CELLS. That is A is built using storyboard objects only as opposed to programmatically. B is also a UITableView but built programmatically with DYNAMIC CELLS. So I wired up Segues (with identifiers set in the storyboard) from each cells in A to the B Tableview.

Now what I would like to have is to know which segue has been pushed when a row in A is selected. I know this can easily be done if I create the cells in view A programmatically and use the prepare/perform segue methods. But since the contents in A will never change, I do not want to go that route. Reason why I am trying to find out how to check which segue has been pushed when I select a given row in A. Ideally there would be some for of a method DIDPERFORMSEGUE: (Segue identifier) I could call from the B Viewcontroller.

Thanks very much for your help and suggestions.

Comment: Are you trying to do this without any code in controller A? If so, I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Yes that is the goal. I would imagine there is a way to know from B since the segue is being performed (ie hidden code that knows what segue is being performed).

Comment: Well, keep imagining, but I think you're out of luck.

Comment: Ok thanks vm for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your "A" TableView, you should be able to peek at which row was poked, and then push that information to your "B" table.  For example:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"UITableView_B"]){
        BTableViewController *vc = (BTableViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath *path;
        path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        [vc setSelectedPath:path];
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.  Best of luck.

*Edit*: Probably obvious, but in the above "self.tableView" is an outlet pointing at the UITableView.

**Update**
Personally, I'd bite the bullet and make a class for "A", but in the interest of hacking - it should be possible to reach back and get data from the previous view.  This is 'bad code' (imo) and assumes you're using a Navigation Controller - and that the previous view is an "A" table, etc... Without further ado - is should be possible to just do this:

```
NSArray * views = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
NSUInteger prevViewIndex = [views count] - 2;
UIViewController * previousView = [views objectAtIndex:prevViewIndex];
ATableViewController * aTableViewController = (ATableViewController *) previousView;
NSIndexPath *path = [aTableViewController.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for your answer. However, I was trying to check which segue was pushed without any code done in A. I was trying to check it in B. But as rdelmar pointed out to me above, it seems that this is impossible to do so I am going to implement this in A. Thanks again.

Comment: I updated my answer with a quick-hack.  It should do the trick.

Comment: Now thats creative! thanks very much but I think you are right. I ll just bite that bullet. I am implementing using the traditional method  (prepareforsegue). Thanks again Dave.

Comment: @Joel, - thanks for the green check.  In your case; when you make your UITableView subclass, the only method it needs is the prepareForSegue.  You can delete everything else the template generates.

Comment: Hey Dave, following our exchanges on this topic (and for others benefit) here is a suggestion I received from another forum: "One way is to add a property that keeps track of the segue selected. You could add it to the vc that is presented. You could also add it to the appdelegate. Or you could send an NSNotification to the vc or other such class object that needs to know the segue selected." I opted to just build up the classes in A and use the perform segue but I thought these were also neat solutions. Hope it helps someone.  cheers.

Comment: @Joel, sure you can do those things.  To "track the segue", you just pass B-tableView the segue.identifier instead of path.row in your prepareForSegue: method.  That might be slightly more maintainable.  I don't like the notification idea.  Glad to hear you're over this hump.  Best of luck with your app.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I've needed to do this myself, but if you *really* don't want to change the source view controller or if you have a frequent need to identify the segue from the destination view controller, one way to do it would be to create your own UIStoryboardSegue subclass. A segue already knows about the destination view controller, so it's a simple matter to give the destination a chance to inspect the segue. Something like this should do the trick:

```
@interface MyStoryboardSegue : UIStoryboardSegue
@end

@implementation MyStoryboardSegue

- (void)perform
{
    [super perform]

    if ([self.destinationViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(didPerformSegue:)]) {
        [self.destinationViewController didPerformSegue:self];
    }
}

@end
```

It's not a great solution if you're already using UIStoryboardSegue subclasses for other reasons. And in fact, I haven't even tested the code, so perhaps there are some snags I haven't thought of yet. The point, however, is that if you want a segue to notify the destination when it executes, you can probably arrange it.